# Getting Links from an internal web page

Tags: development, web-services, asp.net

I have an internal company's web page and I need to extract a link from that page
what I tried is

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {                    
                string pattern = @"(<a.*?>.*?</a>)";

                MatchCollection hreflist;

                string Url = client.DownloadString("https://collaborate.citi.net/docs/DOC-908807");                

                hreflist = Regex.Matches(Url, pattern);

                Console.WriteLine("Total number of links in Url: " + hreflist.Count + "\n\n");
```

But this code doesn't seems to work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download HtmlAgilityPack

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            var sourceCode = wc.DownloadString("http://dota-trade.com/equipment?order=name");
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(sourceCode);
            var node = doc.DocumentNode;
            var nodes = node.SelectNodes("//a");
            List<string> links = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in nodes)
            {
                var link = item.Attributes["href"].Value;
                links.Add(link.Contains("http") ? link : "http://dota-trade.com" +link);
            }
      
  
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\WriteLines.txt", links);
```

Comment: Can you please Explain me all the links that you have used in your code, as i have only one url and that i have mentioned in my question. i am bit confused with all the links that you have used.

Comment: Code updated and simplified.@TausifKhan

Comment: Thanks buddy :)